Embedding a positive-weighted undirected graph in Euclidean space?
Say I have a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ undirected positively-weighted edges. I want to embed that graph into $k$-dimensional Euclidean aka Cartesian space such that $k$ is minimal. A valid embedding means that each vertex is mapped to a $k$-dimensional Cartesian point such that that Euclidean distance between two vertices is equal to the corresponding edge weight (assuming the edge exists [i.e. has non-zero weight]).
For example, if one was given a planar graph that obeyed the triangle inequality, then it should be a simple matter to embed that into 2D space to make it look like a network of roads. But I imagine that in general, one would have to embed into higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces.

To be clear, I want an efficient algorithm that takes an adjacency matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n\times n}$ (or adjacency list) as input, and outputs a list of $n$ $k$-dimensional points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ such that $A[i,j] = \left\lVert x_i - x_j \right\rVert$ if $A[i,j] \neq 0$. Furthermore, $k$ should be minimal.
I've found a bunch of stuff on unweighted graphs, but I wanted an answer for the weighted graph question.

As described at the beginning of page 3 here (https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs369m/cs369mlecture1.pdf) you won't be able to do this unless you allow some distortion.
